# What did I miss in EXPLAIN that hinted at server crippling loads?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, greatest-n-per-group, explain

I reviewed `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output for a query and found a couple subqueries were scanning the whole table. This is done to get only the most recent record in those tables related to an appointment.

After some research, I decided that it would be reasonable to use a lateral join on those subqueries to dramatically reduce the amount of data scanned. `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` suggested the cost of the whole query with lateral joins would be about a quarter of the original. So we proceeded.

Within two hours of deploying the query change, our DB server was maxed out at 100% and basically unresponsive.  Reverting the query to use subqueries scanning the tables restored the CPU usage to something sane.  Our DB is running in AWS RDS for PostgreSQL using a t2.xlarge.  Performance insights showed a substantial increase in ClientWrite. See [image: database load graph].

The query using subqueries along with the `EXPLAIN` output: https://explain.depesz.com/s/wES6.

```
select appointments.*, 
    reportSnapshots.created_at as latestSnapshotTime, 
    responses.created_at as latestResponseTime  
from appointments 
    left join (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON  (appointmentId) created_at, appointmentId
            FROM reportSnapshots
            ORDER BY appointmentId, created_at DESC
    ) reportSnapshots on appointments.id = reportSnapshots.appointmentId 
    left join (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON  (appointmentId) created_at, appointmentId
            FROM responses
            ORDER BY appointmentId, created_at DESC
    ) responses on appointments.id = responses.appointmentId 
where appointments.organizationId = 16 and appointments.locationId = '51' 
    and appointments.cancelled = false and appointments.filteredIn = true 
    and start between '2021-05-04T00:00:00-06:00' and '2021-05-04T23:59:59-06:00' 
    and appointments.locationId in (61,60,140,53,138,130,133,131,55,51,100) 
group by appointments.id, 
    reportSnapshots.created_at, 
    responses.created_at
order by start ASC, start ASC, id ASC 
limit 100
```

The query using lateral join along with the `EXPLAIN` output: https://explain.depesz.com/s/B2vp.

```
select appointments.*, 
    reportSnapshots.created_at as latestSnapshotTime, 
    responses.created_at as latestResponseTime  
from appointments 
    left join lateral (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON  (appointmentId) created_at, appointmentId
            FROM reportSnapshots
        WHERE reportSnapshots.appointmentId = appointments.id
            ORDER BY appointmentId, created_at DESC
    ) reportSnapshots on appointments.id = reportSnapshots.appointmentId 
    left join lateral (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON  (appointmentId) created_at, appointmentId
            FROM responses
        WHERE responses.appointmentId = appointments.id
            ORDER BY appointmentId, created_at DESC
    ) responses on appointments.id = responses.appointmentId 
where appointments.organizationId = 16 and appointments.locationId = '51' 
    and appointments.cancelled = false and appointments.filteredIn = true 
    and start between '2021-05-04T00:00:00-06:00' and '2021-05-04T23:59:59-06:00' 
    and appointments.locationId in (61,60,140,53,138,130,133,131,55,51,100) 
group by appointments.id, 
    reportSnapshots.created_at, 
    responses.created_at
order by start ASC, start ASC, id ASC 
limit 100
```

Obviously, I did not understand what the `EXPLAIN` output was telling me about the queries. What did I miss that could have told me the DB load would be higher with the lateral join query despite a lower cost?

Comment: Referencing your load chart, where on that did you deploy the change, and then where did you revert it?

Comment: Some more basic information would be instrumental for this performance question. Consider instructions here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` suggested the cost of the whole query with lateral joins would be about a quarter of the original.

[`EXPLAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) (*estimating* the cost) suggests `40,089.36` vs. `189,883.92` unicorn points.
But [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) (*measuring* actual execution times) disagrees and shows `2,502.031` ms vs. `1,835.193` ms, so around 1/3 slower. There can be many reasons why the estimation is off target. Most prominently cost settings and statistics. See:

- [Keep PostgreSQL from sometimes choosing a bad query plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8229000/939860)

That said, the query can probably be ***much*** faster (by orders of magnitude). We only got limited information, but I suppose you want something like this:

```
SELECT a.*
     , rs.created_at AS latestsnapshottime  -- maybe use COALESCE?
     , rp.created_at AS latestresponsetime
FROM   appointments a
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT rs.created_at
   FROM   reportsnapshots rs
   WHERE  rs.appointmentid = a.id
   ORDER  BY rs.created_at DESC  -- NULLS LAST ?
   LIMIT  1
   ) rs ON true
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT rp.created_at
   FROM   responses rp
   WHERE  rp.appointmentid = a.id
   ORDER  BY rp.created_at DESC  -- NULLS LAST ?
   LIMIT  1
   ) rp ON true
WHERE  a.organizationid = 16
AND    a.locationid = '51'
AND    a.cancelled = FALSE
AND    a.filteredin = TRUE
AND    a.start BETWEEN '2021-05-04T00:00:00-06:00' AND '2021-05-04T23:59:59-06:00'
AND    a.locationid IN (61,60,140,53,138,130,133,131,55,51,100)
-- GROUP  BY a.id, rs.created_at, rp.created_at  -- not needed, I guess
ORDER  BY a.start, a.id
LIMIT  100;
```

`DISTINCT ON` is a great tool, but for different situations. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

Retrieving a single row from each `LATERAL` subquery like I suggest can  use an index and is super fast. Ideally, you have theses indexes:

```
reportsnapshots (appointmentid, created_at DESC NULLS LAST)
responses       (appointmentid, created_at DESC NULLS LAST)
```

Further reading:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)

If `created_at` is defined `NOT NULL`, a simpler index on `(appointmentid, created_at)` is just as good (and preferable). See:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511492/939860)
- [Why does ORDER BY NULLS LAST affect the query plan on a primary key?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/254731/why-does-order-by-nulls-last-affect-the-query-plan-on-a-primary-key/254761#254761)

Plus an index on the outer table. The one in use now (`appointments_organizationId_status_start_idx`) doesn't seem too bad. But I suspect more potential, depending on undisclosed information.

You probably don't have to aggregate in the outer query, since both subqueries return a single row each (even your original).

**Alternatively**, use plain **correlated subqueries** with `max()` for your simple case. Probably even faster, yet:

```
SELECT a.*
     , (SELECT max(rs.created_at)
        FROM   reportsnapshots rs
        WHERE  rs.appointmentid = a.id) AS latestsnapshottime
     , (SELECT max(rp.created_at)
        FROM   responses rp
        WHERE  rp.appointmentid = a.id) AS latestresponsetime
FROM   appointments a
WHERE  ...
LIMIT  100;
```

See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)

---

Aside 1: `BETWEEN` is typically no good for timestamps. See:

- [https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_BETWEEN_.28especially_with_timestamps.29](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_BETWEEN_.28especially_with_timestamps.29)
- [How to add a day/night indicator to a timestamp column?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/267869/how-to-add-a-day-night-indicator-to-a-timestamp-column/267877#267877)

Aside 2: In your first query plan I see `Sort Method: external merge Disk: 3,856kB` and `Sort Method: external merge Disk: 17,752kB`, which indicates  a lack of `work_mem`. The same problem does not surface in the 2nd plan, nor will it for my queries. But look into your server configuration. Related:

- [Optimize simple query using ORDER BY date and text](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48630/optimize-simple-query-using-order-by-date-and-text/48633#48633)

Answer (score 3):

You looked at the estimated costs of the query and saw that it was less, but you overlooked two important things.  The actual measured time was longer (although not by much), not shorter.  And the actual row count was off by a factor of 32 from the estimate.  Both of these are pretty important flags.

So while you apparently did the EXPLAIN with ANALYZE, you apparently ignored all the important data provided by using ANALYZE.  (Or maybe you originally just did EXPLAIN, and only repeated it with ANALYZE as part of your post-mortem write-up.  In that case, well, that was your mistake.  About the only reason to do EXPLAIN without ANALYZE is if the query will never finish with it, or if actually running it will modify data you don't want to modify)

If it was faster, you should have seen it being faster, not slower.  And even if you had somehow not noticed it being slower, the way-wrong row estimates should have made you suspicious that the estimates were not reliable.  Especially when you see it was thought to do a seq scan of a large table just once, but instead it did the scan 32 times. (And the reason for that, in turn, seems to be that you are missing an index on `responses (appointmentid)`, or better yet on `responses (appointmentid, created_at)`.  With one of those indexes, your proposed query would have actually been much faster than the old one--but making it faster doesn't seem to be what your actual question is about.)

So there was ample evidence in the ANALYZE part of the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) that it would not actually be an improvement.  But as for crippling the server, I don't see evidence in the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) that it would do that.  But I also don't see evidence that it actually did do that.  I don't see indications of a crippled server anywhere in your load chart.  The load chart seems to show one and a half cycles of, well, something.  But what you describe is only one cycle (apply the new query, see problem, revert), so how does that line up with the load chart?

In any event, high ClientWrite wait events indicate a problem with the clients (or the network, or maybe indicate no problem at all), not a problem with the server.  The server is operating so well that it is generating requested data faster than the clients (or network) can process it.

I suspect the main problem you ran into is that you exhausted a credit balance on your t-class instance, either CPU credit balance or IO credit balance.  That would not show up on an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` taken during a time when the credit balance was not exhausted. (And I don't know how it would show up on Amazon RDS's flavor of load chart, but would not be surprised if it doesn't how up in an obvious manner).

Comment: *"About the only reason to do EXPLAIN without ANALYZE is if the query will never finish with it."* That, and `INSERT`, `UPDATE`,  `DELETE` - which are actually executed with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.